# three.js lightbox not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

I would like to create a lightbox/popup of a three.js model. My HTML canvas is appearing  but I cannot see the three.js model inside the canvas and I don't understand why. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/cool_brian/e72duxwc/2/

My three.js function:

```
function cube() {

var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,    0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(myCanvas.offsetWidth, myCanvas.offsetHeight);
renderer.setClearColorHex(0xffffff, 1);
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.02;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

};

JQuery Light box:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

//alert("the doc is ready");
$('.lightbox_trigger').click(function (e) {

    //prevent default action (hyperlink)
    e.preventDefault();

    var lightbox =
        '<div id="lightbox">' +
        '<p>Click to close</p>' +
        '<div id="content">' +
        '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800px" height="800px"style="border:10px solid #000000;">' +
        '</canvas>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    //insert lightbox HTML into page
    $('body').append(lightbox);

});

//Click anywhere on the page to get rid of lightbox window
$('#lightbox').live('click', function () {
    $('#lightbox').hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<p>lightbox demo
    <ul>
        <li> <a class="lightbox_trigger" onClick="alert(link 1)"> alert </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a class="lightbox_trigger" onClick="cube();"> three.js example </a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "onClick" aswell as adding click events with jquery.
1 . I removed the `onClick`.

Your path to the external three.js was wrong and you also told jsfiddle to include it.
2 . I removed the included (framework section) three.js and add the correct github path to the latest three.js (external resources section).

3 . I changed a couple of the class and function calls for the latest three.js.

4 . I changed the way the canvas is being added to the page.

5 . I added `cancelAnimationFrame` when lightbox is closed.

It should now display how you expect.
BUT.
It will only close the first 'lightbox' as you are creating a new lightbox every time the text is clicked, but only hide it when it is closed. This results in more than 1 lightbox div being in the DOM (but only 1 visible).
To correct this I suggest you create the lightbox div when the page loads, hide it, then just add a new scene and show the lighbox when needed and remove the scene and hide the lightbox when appropriate.
Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/e72duxwc/4/